# Java Server faces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf-1.2

i have two input texts named as password and confirm password. but in confirm password inputtext should not allow the paste content from the password input text. please give me good solution..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: I think this is related to javascript and html, tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery

```
$("#confirmPassword").bind('paste', function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
      $("#confirmPassword").val("");
});
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` and `$(this).val("");` maybe? :)

Comment: how to call this jQuery from inputtext

Comment: You just need to tell jQuery that on paste we are binding this function execution

Answer (score 0):

This should be done using JavaScript. There should be `onpaste` event. You can Google for it.